# Pop up a notification div that fadesOut after 1 sec in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
notDiv=$("<div></div>");
    $(notDiv)
        .attr("id", "notification")
        .html("Item added to shoppingCart successfully")
        .appendTo("#main");

    $(notDiv)
        .fadeIn()
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut()
        .remove();
```

I want to pop up a notification div when a merchandise is selected.

but the div does not appear on the screen!!

Where have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay affects won't affect remove. See docs:

> It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue.

from https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Should be

```
 $(notDiv)
        .fadeIn()
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(function(){
                   $(this).remove();
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `notDiv` is already an `jQuery` object, you don't need to make again `$(notDiv)`.

How @julien-grégoire mentioned, you have to put the `remove` inside `fadeOut`.

You can **create a new plugin** that makes the notification events order, `fadeIn`, `delay`, `fadeOut` and `remove`.

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeTemporary = function(speed) {
    $(this)
        .fadeIn()
        .delay(speed)
        .fadeOut(function(){
             $(this).remove();
        });
}

$("#main").click(function(){
    notDiv=$("<div></div>");
    notDiv.attr("id", "notification")
        .html("Item added to shoppingCart successfully")
        .appendTo("#main")
        .fadeTemporary(3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"> Main </div>
```